Store multiple AUCs and CIs in a dataframe with pROC
I am trying to get calculate multiple AUCs and CIs using pROC, and store the results into a table. The original data is as below. D is an outcome and V1, 2 etc are variables.



D
V1
V2




0
0.1
3


0
0.1
4


1
0.2
3


1
0.1
4



So far I have tried putting the variable names into a vector and then using map function as below:
vars <- c("V1", "V2") 
map_df(mget(vars), function(x) {tmp <- roc(data$D~x) c(auc = auc(tmp), ci = ci(tmp))}, .id = 'marker') -> result

When I run the code I get the error "Error: value for ‘V1’ not found". Can anyone see why it can't recognise the variable column titles?
